# MTLLoader breaks other 3js code and isn't loading texture right

Tags: three.js

I am having trouble getting the MTLLoader to work correctly. I have already been able to use the OBJLoader by itself to load the 3d object and I have a camera that works properly too in my scene. When I try and use the MTLLoader with the OBJLoader the object loads but it breaks my other three.js code. I get these errors:

```
three.js:24415 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
at initMaterial (three.js:24415)
at setProgram (three.js:24493)
at WebGLRenderer.renderBufferDirect (three.js:23552)
at renderObject (three.js:24269)
at renderObjects (three.js:24239)
at WebGLRenderer.render (three.js:24037)
at render (demo2.html:480)
```

The object loads and it looks like some textures load but the textures don't look right, the camera breaks. I have been having trouble with this and could really use some guidance.

Here is my MTLLoader code by itself

```
    var mesh = null;
    var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    mtlLoader.load( 'dapHouseGood5.mtl', function( materials ) {
    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.load( 'dapHouseGood5.obj', function ( object ) {

    mesh = object;
    scene.add( mesh );

    } );
```

Here is the rest of my three.js code for reference

```
                <script>
                /* global THREE */      

        function main() {
          const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
          const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
          const renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

            var kitchenCameraActive = false;

            document.getElementById("roomSelect").addEventListener("change", changeIt);

        function changeIt(e) {
            document.getElementById(e.target.value).click();
            console.log(e);
        }

          var fov = 45;
          var aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
          var near = 0.1;
          var far = 100;
          var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
          camera.position.set(-97.570, 5.878, -5.289);
          camera.rotation.set(0,0,0);

          const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
          controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
          controls.update();

          document.getElementById("kitchen").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);         
          document.getElementById("bathroom").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);        
          document.getElementById("deck").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);        
          document.getElementById("livingRoom").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);        
          document.getElementById("bedRoom").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);
          document.getElementById("walkway").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);
          document.getElementById("sideHouse").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);
          document.getElementById("frontPorch").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);
          document.getElementById("garageDoor").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);
          document.getElementById("insideGarage").addEventListener("click", changeCamera);

        function changeCamera(e) {
            camera.rotation.set(e.toElement.attributes[5].nodeValue, 
e.toElement.attributes[6].nodeValue, e.toElement.attributes[7].nodeValue);              
            camera.fov = e.toElement.attributes[4].nodeValue;
            camera.position.set(e.toElement.attributes[1].nodeValue, 
e.toElement.attributes[2].nodeValue, e.toElement.attributes[3].nodeValue);      
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            if (e.target.id == "walkway" || e.target.id == "frontPorch" || e.target.id == 
"garageDoor" || e.target.id == "insideGarage")
                {
                    controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
                    controls.update();
                }               
            if(e.target.id == "kitchen"){
            controls.target.set(7, 6, 7);
            }
            if(e.target.id == "bathroom"){
            controls.target.set(-9,15,-7);
            }
            if(e.target.id == "deck"){
            controls.target.set(31, 7, 1);
            }
            if(e.target.id == "livingRoom"){
            controls.target.set(-12.5, 1.5, -18.5);
            }
            if(e.target.id == "bedRoom"){
            controls.target.set(-15.7, 14, -21);
            }
            if(e.target.id == "insideGarage"){
            controls.target.set(24.405, 6.733, -6.425);
            }

            controls.update();  
            console.log(e);
        }

          const scene = new THREE.Scene();
          scene.background = new THREE.Color('black');
          {
            const planeSize = 40;
          }

          {
            const skyColor = 0xB1E1FF;  // light blue
            const groundColor = 0xB97A20;  // brownish orange
            const intensity = 1;
            const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(skyColor, groundColor, intensity);
            scene.add(light);
          }

          {
            const color = 0xFFFFFF;
            const intensity = 1;
            const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
            light.position.set(5, 10, 2);
            scene.add(light);
            scene.add(light.target);
          }

            var mesh = null;

            var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            mtlLoader.load( 'dapHouseGood5.mtl', function( materials ) {

              materials.preload();

              var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
              objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
              objLoader.load( 'dapHouseGood5.obj', function ( object ) {

                mesh = object;
                scene.add( mesh );

              } );

            } );

          function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
            const canvas = renderer.domElement;
            const width = canvas.clientWidth;
            const height = canvas.clientHeight;
            const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
            if (needResize) {
              renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
            }
            return needResize;
          }

          function render() {
            if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
              const canvas = renderer.domElement;
              camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
              camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            }

              renderer.render(scene, camera);

            requestAnimationFrame(render);
          }

          requestAnimationFrame(render);

            function onPositionChange(o) {
            console.log("position changed in object");
            console.log(o);
            console.log('camera_default: '+camera.position.x+', '+camera.position.y+', 
'+camera.position.z);
            console.log('camera_default: '+camera.rotation.x+', '+camera.rotation.y+', 
'+camera.rotation.z);
            console.log(camera.fov);
                console.log('quaternion_default: '+camera.quaternion.x+', '+
                camera.quaternion.y+', '+camera.quaternion.z+', '+camera.quaternion.w);
            }

            controls.addEventListener('change', onPositionChange);

        var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
        var raycaster, mouse = { x : 0, y : 0};

        init();

        function init () {
            //Usual setup code here.
            raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
            renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'click', raycast, false );
        }

        function raycast ( e ) {
            //1. sets the mouse position with a coordinate system where the center
            //   of the screen is the origin
            mouse.x = ( e.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = - ( e.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

            //2. set the picking ray from the camera position and mouse coordinates
            raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
            //var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,   -( 
event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
            //raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse3D, camera );       

            //3. compute intersections
            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );

            for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
                console.log( intersects[ i ].object.name );
            }
        }               
        }
        main();
            </script>
```